# Cisco ASA 5500 Series: Send email of logging message monitored interface up/down

Tags: cisco-asa

May I know is it possible to only send email of logging message interface up/down instead of based on severity level?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I admit, I have never attempted this before.  However, it appears you should be able to with a properly configured custom "**Event List**".

According to the Cisco ASDM User Guide (excerpts):

> **Event Lists**
>
> The Event Lists pane lets you create custom lists of events that are used to choose which syslog messages are sent to a
> specific destination. After you enable logging and configure the
> logging parameters using the Logging Setup pane, create one or more
> lists of events in the Event Lists pane. Use these event lists in the
> Logging Filters pane to specify a logging destination for each list of
> events. To access this pane, choose **Configuration > Device
> Management > Logging > Event Lists.**
>
> To create custom lists of events to send to a specific logging
> destination, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Click Add to display the Add Event List dialog box.
> 2. In the Name field, enter the name of the event list. No spaces are allowed.
> 3. In the Event Class/Severity area, click Add to display the Add Class and Severity Filter dialog box.
> 4. Choose the event class from the drop-down list.
> 5. Choose the severity level from the drop-down list.
> 6. Click OK to close this dialog box.
> 7. In the Message ID Filters area, click Add to display the Add Syslog
>    Message ID Filter dialog box.
> 8. In the Message IDs field, enter a syslog message ID or range of IDs
>    (for example, 101001-199012) to include in the filter.
> 9. Click OK to close this dialog box.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asdm/6_1/user/guide/usergd/cfglog.html#wp1201753

The line up/down Message ID can be found in the "Cisco ASA Series Syslog Messages" documentation.

```
%ASA-1-105006: (Primary) Link status Up on interface interface_name.
%ASA-1-105007: (Primary) Link status Down on interface interface_name.
```

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog-guide/syslogs/logsevp.html

I would be interested in the resulting configuration.